# Appium client doesn't allow to select specific element on the screen of react-native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, automated-tests, appium

I'm working on the **react-native** application and using **Appium** for automation testing. I'm facing a problem on the **Appium** sandbox. On certain pages I can't select a specific element. Any attempt to tap on the screen to select a specific element ends with highlighting the entire screen/container, with no access to any child element inside of the container. On some screens, everything is working fine.

I first thought that perhaps the problem is in layout or certain elements. I checked the styles of the elements and the space that they are taking on the screens and didn't notice that something is taking the entire screen. On the page, I'm also using components from the **lottie-react-native** library, I thought that maybe something is wrong with the elements, but on other pages, I don't have such an issue. Perhaps anyone faced this problem as well?

Thank you in advance.